# Data Tables: Creating New Column By Examining Multiple Columns On Multiple Rows

Tags: r, data.table

I presently have a data table containing two columns - 'id' and 'prevId'. I would like to create a chain of ids by starting with a first row, finding a second row whose 'id' equals the first row's 'prevId', and repeating this process until 'prevId' is blank.

I would then like to identify the 'id' in the end of the chain without a 'prevId', and create a new column listing this originator 'id' for every row.

Below is an example of my desired output:

```
   id                  prevId originatorId createdAt
1: 11a                        11a          2018/1/12 
2: 11b                 11a    11a          2018/1/13
3: 11c                 11b    11a          2018/1/14
4: 12a                        12a          2018/1/12        
5: 12b                 12a    12a          2018/1/13
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

I have noticed a caveat while testing some of the proposed solutions. There may be instances where an element has a 'prevId' that is not seen as an 'id' in any other element. If I were to use to run chinsoon's solution:

```
DT[, originatorId:=id[1L], by=cumsum(prevId==“”)]
```

It would cause such elements to list the closest peer without a 'prevId' as its originator, even if that peer was not part of the id-prevId chain. An example:

```
   id                  prevId originatorId createdAt
1: 10a                        10a          2018/1/12 
2: 11b                 11a    10a          2018/1/13
3: 11c                 11b    10a          2018/1/14
```

In this instance, '11a' should be the originator for the 2nd and 3rd elements, but because it isn't present, '10a' gets the spot instead. Is there a tweak that could fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for DT[, originatorId:=id[1L], by=cumsum(prevId==“”)]

Comment: This is almost perfect chinsoon. One minor problem is that if there is a row where there is no earlier row with a 'id' equal to its 'prevId', it will set the closest row without a prevId as its originator. See the example in my edit. Would you know a tweak that could fix this?

Comment: Use prevId[2L] instead of id[1L] if you want the whole originator to be 11a. If not, can you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now recursive with two recursive steps, using `dplyr` and `data.table` functionality.

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c("11a", "11b", "11c", "12a", "12b"), prevId = c(NA,  "11a", "11b", NA, "12a")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

data.table(left_join(x = dt
       , y = dt[,.(prevId)]
       , by = c("id" = "prevId")) %>% left_join(
                                            y = dt[,.(id,prevId)]
                                            , by = c("prevId" = "id")
       ))[, .(id, prevId, originatorId = ifelse(is.na(prevId.y), ifelse(is.na(prevId), id, prevId), prevId.y ))]

>  id   prevId  originatorId
1: 11a   <NA>          11a
2: 11b    11a          11a
3: 11c    11b          11a
4: 12a   <NA>          12a
5: 12b    12a          12a
```

Expanded the example to incorporate the comment by @Michael. It is pretty scalable and allows to adjust the number of recursive steps, by adding additional joins into the pipe. It saves the resulting joined data.table after each iteration and thus allows to follow the matching steps pretty easily. Finally, the results of each join are combined and the resulting table should offer a good overview over the chain of ids in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x = dt
          , y = dt[,.(prevId)]
          , by = c("id" = "prevId")) %>% data.table(.) %>% { . ->> dt.join.1}   %>% left_join(x = .
                                                                                 , y = dt[,.(Second.id = id, Second.prevId = prevId)]
                                                                                , by = c("prevId" = "Second.id")) %>%  data.table(.) %>% { . ->> dt.join.2}


dt.join.final.data <- rbindlist(list(  dt.join.1
                                       , dt.join.2)
                                , fill = TRUE
                                , idcol = "id"
                                , use.names = TRUE)
```

The resulting data.table looks then like this:

```
> dt.join.final.data
    id  id prevId Second.prevId
 1:  1 11a   <NA>          <NA>
 2:  1 11b    11a          <NA>
 3:  1 11c    11b          <NA>
 4:  1 12a   <NA>          <NA>
 5:  1 12b    12a          <NA>
 6:  2 11a   <NA>          <NA>
 7:  2 11b    11a          <NA>
 8:  2 11c    11b           11a
 9:  2 12a   <NA>          <NA>
10:  2 12b    12a          <NA>
```

Comment: Great logic hannes! I apologise for not specifying in the question that I was looking for a solution that could scale the number of ids in each chain. I tested your solution and it works perfectly with those chain lengths but breaks once the lengths differ. Would you happen to know a fix?

Comment: Since, I was also looking for the exact same problem. I created solution which is easily scalable to more than one recursive steps. I will try to adapt it to your MWE and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Much appreciated hannes!

Comment: Updated the answer, please check if that's helping you.

Comment: Thanks Hannes! I made a recursive variant of your solution and am making great progress.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by defining a recursive function and applying it to all rows.

```
find_originatorId = function(current_row, df){
    if(current_row[["prevId"]] == ""){
        current_row[["id"]]
    } else {
        parent_row = df[df$id == current_row[["prevId"]],]
        find_originatorId(parent_row, df)
    }
}

df$originatorId = apply(df, 1, find_originatorId, df)
```