# Extracting information from a hierarchical relationship chain

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Initially, the data was presented as different Ids having a parent-child relationship and each line represented a different trade and its id.
The original dataset, which I need to analyze looks like this.

```
dt.original.data <- structure(list(msg_seq_nb = c("0005747", "0005747", "0005765", "0005765", "0005783", "0005783", "0008333", "0008333", "0008494", 
                                  "0008494", "0008556", "0008556", "0008560", "0008560", "0013622", "0013622", "0013797", "0013797", "0024541", "0024541", "0024569"
    ), orig_msg_seq_nb = c(NA, NA, "0005747", "0005747", "0005765", "0005765", "0005783", "0005783", "0008333", "0008333", "0008494", 
                           "0008494", "0008556", "0008556", "0008560", "0008560", "0013622", "0013622", "0013797", "0013797", "0024541")
    , trc_st = c("T","C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R")
    , trd_rpt_dt = structure(c(15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987), class = "Date")
    , trd_rpt_tm = c(34838, 34853, 34853, 34863, 34863, 36231, 36231, 36305, 36305, 36328, 36328, 36330, 36330, 38831, 38831, 38925, 38925, 42984, 42984, 43002, 43002))
    , row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

   >  dt.original.data
    msg_seq_nb orig_msg_seq_nb trc_st trd_rpt_dt trd_rpt_tm
 1:    0005747            <NA>      T 2013-10-09      34838
 2:    0005747            <NA>      C 2013-10-09      34853
 3:    0005765         0005747      R 2013-10-09      34853
 4:    0005765         0005747      C 2013-10-09      34863
 5:    0005783         0005765      R 2013-10-09      34863
 6:    0005783         0005765      C 2013-10-09      36231
 7:    0008333         0005783      R 2013-10-09      36231
 8:    0008333         0005783      C 2013-10-09      36305
```

As you can see there's a hierarchical relationship between all the trades entered via the connection between `orig_msg_seq_nb` to `msg_seq_nb`. Therefore, I managed to used recursive joins to basically add matching combinations into one row.
This was done, using the answer I provided to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395260/5795592
and an excerpt of this result looks like this:

```
>      msg_seq_nb Initial.Trade.Status Initial.Trd.Rpt.Dt Initial.Trd.Rpt.Tm J2.Msg.Nb J2.Trade.Status J2.Trd.Rpt.Tm
   1:    0005747                    T         2013-10-09              34838   0005765               R         34853
   2:    0005747                    T         2013-10-09              34838   0005765               C         34863
```

I now would like to analyze each relationship chain and would like to extract the status at the end of each relationship chain. So in case of the the example data above, since the last entered trade status in trc_st of `msg_seq_nb` `0008333` is `C`I would need to remove all the msg_seq_nb of the hierarchical chain.

Based on the final status of this relationship chain - which was originally a sequence of different trades - determines if the trades with ids stay in the original data set or if the initial status has to be updated with the final status, i.e. the status after the last recursive step.

It is somehow related to this SQL question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96098/finding-the-end-of-a-relationship-chain-optimally

Comment: For me it's not really clear what you are asking / trying to achive. To get from wide to long use `melt.data.table`.

Comment: Removed that part with the data structure. I would like to extract the last status of a relationship chain. And additionally I am not sure if the data as it is now, is the best way to represent this hierarchical relationship chain. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I’d start with a simple `list()` to represent hierarchical data in R. But of course there are alternatives: see library([data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)) - this also makes filter functions like `isLeaf` available which seems to be of interest for you. Nevertheless, I think you should specify your expected result with regards to your provided example. Also if you are not sure if the current representation is useful, give an example of the hierarchical data you were processing to get to your `data.table`.

Comment: I've updated the question and also took a look at your suggestion of the `data.tree` package and in connection with the results of the recursive joins, I think I can best describe this kind of structure.

Comment: So in the end it's all about transitions not hierarchy. To get that last transition you'll simply need to get rid of all duplicated values: `dt.original.data[!msg_seq_nb %in% dt.original.data[duplicated(dt.original.data, by="msg_seq_nb")]$msg_seq_nb]`

Comment: Well, it's not so easy to just remove the duplicates by the `msg_seq_nb`, since it's not certain which of the duplicates carries the correct `trc_status`.

Comment: It was a shot in the dark without you providing your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Now, that you provided your expected result here is what I would do:

```
library(data.table)

dt.original.data <- structure(
  list(
    msg_seq_nb = c("0005747", "0005747", "0005765", "0005765", "0005783", "0005783", "0008333", "0008333", "0008494",
                   "0008494", "0008556", "0008556", "0008560", "0008560", "0013622", "0013622", "0013797", "0013797", "0024541", "0024541", "0024569"
), orig_msg_seq_nb = c(NA, NA, "0005747", "0005747", "0005765", "0005765", "0005783", "0005783", "0008333", "0008333", "0008494", 
                       "0008494", "0008556", "0008556", "0008560", "0008560", "0013622", "0013622", "0013797", "0013797", "0024541")
, trc_st = c("T","C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R", "C", "R")
, trd_rpt_dt = structure(c(15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987, 15987), class = "Date")
, trd_rpt_tm = c(34838, 34853, 34853, 34863, 34863, 36231, 36231, 36305, 36305, 36328, 36328, 36330, 36330, 38831, 38831, 38925, 38925, 42984, 42984, 43002, 43002))
, row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

final_transition <- dt.original.data[trc_st != "T" & orig_msg_seq_nb %in% dt.original.data[trc_st == "T"]$msg_seq_nb]
final_transition <- merge(dt.original.data[trc_st == "T", c("trc_st", "trd_rpt_tm", "msg_seq_nb")], final_transition, by.x = "msg_seq_nb", by.y = "orig_msg_seq_nb")

col_names <- c("msg_seq_nb", "Initial.Trade.Status", "Initial.Trd.Rpt.Dt", "Initial.Trd.Rpt.Tm", "J2.Msg.Nb", "J2.Trade.Status", "J2.Trd.Rpt.Tm")

setnames(final_transition, 
         c("msg_seq_nb", "trc_st.x", "trd_rpt_dt", "trd_rpt_tm.x", "msg_seq_nb.y", "trc_st.y", "trd_rpt_tm.y"),
         col_names)
setcolorder(final_transition, col_names)

final_transition
```

Comment: Sorry for making the question so unclear and wasting your time, but this result I already have. I would need a way to determine the trc_status of the last relationship, i.e. between the last rows of `dt.original.data` and based on that would need to remove all the previous `msg_seq_nb`, which would be superseded by the `trc_st` of the last message.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you'd simply post your expected result like e.g. done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506817/how-to-separate-data-from-one-row-into-two-rows-in-r/)

Comment: I don't really know how the results should look like, that's my main problem. I want to be able to basically filter out all messages, which are part of the relationship and determine the final status of this chain. Based on this final status the chain should be completely removed in case of a cancellation or only the last trade should be left in, in case it's a modification.